# Javascript new Date(dateString) handling

Tags: javascript

Would someone explain why formatting the same `dateString` differently gives a different date?

```
> new Date("04/08/1984")
<· Sun Apr 08 1984 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
> new Date("1984-04-08")
<· Sat Apr 07 1984 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the behavior of `Date.parse` (and by extension `new Date`) is largely implementation-defined. If you want reliable behavior, then you should either parse dates manually or use a library such as moment.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a new `Date` object passing a `dateString` parameter to the constructor, it gets parsed using the **[`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** method. Now, quoting from the MDN documentation (emphasis mine):

> #### [Differences in assumed time zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Differences_in_assumed_time_zone)
>
> Given a date string of `"March 7, 2014"` (or `"03/07/2014"`), `parse()` assumes a **local time zone**, but given an ISO format such as `"2014-03-07"` it will assume a **time zone of UTC**. Therefore `Date` objects produced using those strings will represent different moments in time unless the system is set with a local time zone of UTC.

Therefore, since that your are giving the second string in the ISO format, and your local time zone is UTC+6, **you're getting a date which is six hour behind yours, because it gets calculated as UTC+0**. In fact:

```
Apr 07 1984 18:00:00 = Apr 08 1984 00:00:00 - 06:00:00
```

Mystery solved!

Comment: There's never anything fun about working with Date objects... :(

Comment: @tymeJV It's not that complicated: if you often have to deal with dates you learn new tricky exceptions every day, I guess it's just a matter of *time*...

Comment: True...I got pretty dependent on MomentJS...hard to work without it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are adding `0` before the numbers in `"1984-04-08"`. Try the following:

```
new Date("1984-4-8")
```

```js
document.write(new Date("04/08/1984"));
document.write("<br>");
document.write(new Date("1984-4-8"));
```